# Animate a clickable accordian type area?

Tags: jquery

I have a clickable accordian as seen at http://intelligentstudios.co.uk/SimpleHosting/ however I want to have it so after lets say 5-10 seconds it automatically moves onto the next slide. I'm not 100% sure on how to do this, I looked up the animate function but it seems to just break it.
Any help?

- Steve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may find an acceptable solution using JavaScript timers:

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp